# Get Jersey protocol from restlet

Tags: java, jersey

Is there a way to get the protocol which was used to access a restlet? I would to implement like a slightly different behavior when accessing a servlet via HTTPS for example. How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can just inject your `HttpServletRequest` request like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("{storage}/{repository}/{path:.*}")
public void upload(@PathParam("storage") String storage,
                   @PathParam("repository") String repository,
                   @PathParam("path") String path,
                   @Context HttpServletRequest request)
        throws IOException,
               AuthenticationException
{
    System.out.println("Using protocol " + request.getRequestURL().toString().split(":")[0]);
}
```

And this will do the trick.